# Async commands to WebDriver in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to handle the completion of asynchronous function in Selenium.
Asynchronous js function must be started to execute after the click on the button.

Say `listenFor(arguments[0])` listens for the end of the click handlers execution and it starts to listen it before the `click action` was dispatched. In the next function I am listening for click event before `Click action` using async/await of C#.

```
    private async void ExecuteJsAsync(IActionElement button)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started async function");

        var result = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started to listen");

            var script = "listenFor(arguments[0])";
            var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)browser;

            return executor.ExecuteAsyncScript(script);
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Before click");
        new Actions(browser).Click(button).Perform();
        Console.WriteLine("After click");

        _result = await result;
    }
```

But I am getting the next sequence of logs:

```
1. Started async function    
2. Before Click
3. Started to listen
```

Here we can see that `Click` action has not been dispatched. And Question is:

1. Is it possible to execute several tasks asynchronously with Selenium (here `Click action` & `listener`)?
2. Why Selenium can't send `Click action` to the browser here?
3. Do Selenium commands like `Click`, `SendKeys` execute in the main javascripts thread?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, if the logic is like that:

> Asynchronous js function must be started to execute after the click on the button.

then you need to do something like a chain:

```
await Task.Run(() => { new Actions(browser).Click(button).Perform(); }).ContinueWith((_task) => { async code to execute AFTER Click (Perform method completion?) })
```

Sorry, not aware yet about intrinsic logic of Selenium, so not sure it's feasible.